# Running bash -v or bash --v by mistake to know bash version compared to bash -v varname

Tags: bash, variable, session

A few times I mistook `bash -v` or `bash --v` to represent `bash --version` which they do not, as of Bash 4.3.48(1).

From `man bash`, `bash -v` is equivalent to `bash --verbose`; although it returns a large output (allegedly some `bashrc` files, maybe more); I think it just starts a child session.

`bash --v` outputs much less, mainly `bash: --v: invalid option`.

I planned to ask if any of the two could be problematic in an all-default bash but I see no evidence for that and assumes Bash newbies shouldn't be stressed by these.

### My question

I did misunderstood from `man bash`, what's the meaning of `bash -v varname`.

What is the meaning of starting a new bash session with a seemingly undefined variable, or it means to start it with also printing the value of an exported variable`[1`]?

---

### Notes for newcomers:

1. An exported variable is any variable inherited from one shell session to another (say from session 0 to session 1).

Comment: I just read ½ of you post before realising that you was just telling us something that is not part of the question. Then I lost interest (-1).

Comment: I know that, I felt it's not good to delete that as it can help people find this question in Google and have some background.

Comment: If you feel it is needed to give background info, then put it at the end. (Start with what is most important).

Comment: I shortened greatly. I don't agree that one "musn't" start with background info; I think it'll be better sometimes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing two things.

1. Starting `bash` as `bash -v` will start a `bash` shell in which the `set -v` (`set -o verbose`) shell option is set.  It is equivalent to `bash -o verbose` and to `bash --verbose` (one of the few shell options that has a long option equivalent).  One is able to set any of the `abefhkmnptuvxBCHP` options by using their single letters or by using `-o` and their long name directly when starting `bash`, e.g. `bash -x` and `bash -o xtrace`.
2. The `-v varname` comes from, I assume, the description of the built-in `test` command which is able to test whether a variable is set with `test -v varname` or `[ -v varname ]`.

See the `bash` manual or `help set` and `help test` in `bash`.

The long options for `bash` can not be abbreviated.